# How many nodes are needed in a communication satellite network so that it may be a weapon?

Tags: science-based, weapons, space-constructs, radio

It is well known that [phased arrays of antennas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phased_array) employ the wave properties of electromagnetic radiation (radio, microwave, light) to put a bunch of energy on a certain point.  ([Fancy wifi routers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIMO) do this automatically.)

It is also well know that too much EM energy focused on a player's head can cause them damage.

How many satellites similar to the [proposed SpaceX communications satellites](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/11/spacex-plans-worldwide-satellite-internet-with-low-latency-gigabit-speed/) would be necessary to make a lethal weapon?

UPDATES:

1. The target is humans.  The requirement is merely that it be lethal.
2. Despite what some comments and answers say so far, I am sure that if you point enough transmitters at a person's head, they will die.  This question is about how many.

Comment: What are you trying to shoot this thing at? A human being on Earth? An attacking space-ship?

Comment: Technically, a single satellite, if you focus EM energy enough. That's called a laser.

Comment: The trick is going to come down to power output.  I can't seem to find any figures on how powerful the satellite transmitters are on the SpaceX satellites, but realistically a laser (actually this would probably be more like a maser) from space would probably need to fire in the Kilowatt range to do damage, and it would most likely be a sort of prolonged heat damage.  If you wanted something fast and lethal, you'd need at least Megawatt discharge, and if you wanted anything Earth-shattering you'd have to go up into the Gigawatt or maybe Terawatt level.  That will not be easy for a commsat.

Comment: It just occurred to me that while this might not make a good weapons platform, a phased array Ka/Ku band transmitter the size of a commsat orbit would make one hell of a space-based radar/radio telescope.  Maybe that's Elon Musk's secret agenda: planet-sized radar for detecting incoming alien attacks!

Answer (score 8):

## Not a plausible weapon

*THE* phased array is the Navy's [AN/SPY-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AN/SPY-1), the radar component of AEGIS air-defense system. The same radar is used for ballistic missile intercepts with the [SM-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RIM-161_Standard_Missile_3), one of the only demonstrated LEO interceptors on the planet. This is a multi-array, omni-directional phased array with about 6 MW of output power. It also operates in [S-band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S_band) microwaves, which is the same frequency band as a [microwave oven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microwave_oven#Heating_efficiency), so it can definitely be used to cook things.

The bad news is, even with 6 MW output power, it can't really do damage to biologicals. There are apocryphal stories of it cooking seagulls, but humans have been hit by it regularly at short range and barely noticed. During re-fueling at sea, AEGIS warships will steam alongside tankers and they are supposed to 'direct' the phased part of the phased array away from nearby ships. That doesn't always happen. SPY will destroy electronic watches (the [G-Shock](http://www.gshock.com/) is particularly and immediately damaged by S-band radars, for whatever reason) and make your skin itchy, but thats about it.

This kind of weapon is much more plausible as as tool to damage electronics. SPY-1 can and will shutdown helicopter avionics at short range; another time you have to direct the phased array is during helo operations on the aft helo deck.

In conclusion, if 6MW isn't going to get you any damage to people, then the power costs of a space based implementation of this are significant. It would be much easier to spend your 6MW on a good old fashioned laser, or rail gun or something. Heck, from orbit all you have to do is drop rocks to get some serious damage.

Comment: "drop rocks" from orbit is actually very hard. You have to get them in orbit, which is very expensive. Then you have to decelerate them enough so they re-enter. Then they have to survive re-entry. Then they have to be accurate. Then they are not more powerful than conventional weapons.

Comment: What actually happen if you just drop a rock from orbit is ... nothing. The rock stays exactly where you dropped in, relatively to you.

Comment: Dropping a rock from orbit is easy. There are [lots of rocks](http://neo.jpl.nasa.gov/ca/) around, and moving a rock, while at the edge of our current technology, is just a matter of moderate thrust and lots of time. As for accuracy, the [Galileo probe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_Probe) was aimed at Jupiter and hit its latitude target from 5 months out. You don't have to decelerate anything; an elipical orbit, atmospheric braking, and gravity have it covered. Lastly, how many conventional weapons have caused mass extinctions? I'm going with the space rocks as more powerful.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is essentially unanswerable as it stands because, well ... what exactly should this beam be lethal to?

If you're trying to shoot it at a spaceship, well, those should be shielded because there's already a *lot* of radiation in space, and getting through those shields will be quite difficult for something which is not purpose built as a weapon.

If you try to "shoot" at a target on Earth, your "shot" won't make it through the atmosphere. The air/dust will act as interference, and diffuse the energy of the beam, not to mention that our dear planet has a very powerful magnetosphere (keeps us from being microwaved).

You'd be better off creating space mirrors and focusing light into a very narrow beam, which you can then use as, essentially, a laser.

They would only be effective against targets in space, not on Earth (for the same reasons as above). The more of them you focus into a single array, the more powerful the resulting beam, and thus the more deadly your weapon.

Check out author John Ringo's **[Troy Rising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troy_Rising)** series for more information (in this series humanity defends itself from powerful aliens using -among other things - space mirror arrays which channel light into very powerful lasers. It discusses power levels, etc.).

Comment: OP clarified to say humans are being shot

Comment: @Zxyrra This answer is still valid anyway.

Comment: @Mołot I just thought it would help edit as the answer opens with "what exactly should this be lethal to"

Answer (score 1):

**There are 3 major problems:**

1. Increasing number of wave emitters do not scale enough to cover the quadratic loss of waves.
2. You have to perfectly synchronize the waves to not cause interference to each other.
3. You can synchronize waves only against 1 point at a time (unless you place them in an array).

---

**PROBLEM ONE:**

Assume you want to cook something at some point you will definitely need

- a **1 MW** emitter at **1 meter** of distance from the point
- a **4 MW** emitter at **2 meters** of distance from the point

  - 2x2 MW emitter at 2 meters of distance from the point
- a **9 MW** emitter at **3 meters** of distance from the point

  - 3x3 MW emitter at 3 meters of distance from the point

In very densely populated areas there are phone waves emitters [every 400 meters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_site) or so (I'm exagerating to give more power to your weapon).

- You have 1 emitter above your head and it has a power of P
- You have 8 emitters at 200 meters each one
- You have another 16 emitters at 400 meters
- You have another 24 emitters at 600 meters
- ...

The above is a series, where emitters increase linearly, while power emitted decrease more than linearly.

```
TotalPower = 1*P + 8*(P/40000) + 16 * (P/160000)
```

You will never be able to reach 2P, I will not add proof for that.

Basically, given the emitters density you know what is the maximum power you can get.

In example if you count phones there can be phones every 10 meters

```
TotalPowerForPhones = 1p + 8p/100 + 16p/400 + 32p/900
                    < 1p + p/2 + p/4 + p/8  (which is still lesser than 2p)
```

---

**PROBLEM TWO:**

**Synchronization it is not easy at all**, you would need something that can adjust timing of each emitter by small amounts, and you would need also emitters that can keep their phase constant (it is useless phasing something if it lose phasing after few seconds).
However at least synchronization it is possible, Infact you could use a **relativistic synchronizer**, if your emitters are placed on engines that makes them turning very fast (10 times faster than sound in example) you could adjust their phase by TINY FRACTIONS of seconds, not very much, unless your waves have very highfrequency.

Of course you have to stop the relativistic synchronization when waves are synchronized, otherwise doppler effect would change your frequencies (you know, [blue-shift/red-shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect)). So be prepared for periodic big accelerations/decelerations.

You are going to spend orders of magnitude more energy to synchronize the whole weapon than to actually power it.

---

**PROBLEM THREE:**

Unless your emitters are placed in a line you can (on average) cook only 1 single point (in reality, many single sparse points if emitters are equally spaced). The point would have the **diameter comparable to few times the wavelength**. And that point is fixed in space, so if your target moves you  have to re-synchronize your weapon.

---

**THE UNTOLD FOURTH PROBLEM:**

Syncronization is to **aim at a still point**, but if your target moves you have to re-synchronize the whole weapon.

---

**To answer your question:**

> How many nodes are needed in a communication satellite network so that it may be a weapon?

Take the above formula and replace the number of emitters to keep growing the power (in example using cell phones emitters).

```
TotalPower = 1*P + 8*(P/4000) + 16 * (P/16000)
```

Becomes

```
TotalPower = 1*P + 40000*P/40000 + 160000*P/160000 ...
```

**You would need 200001 emitters to get a power of 3P to a target point**. And those emitters should be centered around that point. forming 2 large circles  (one of 400 meters radius and another one of 800).. Basically you need a circle of almost 2 Km in range and with a emitter every 3 centimeters.

You already touched another physical limit, I highly doubt there can be emitters packed as tightly as 3 centimeters from each one, and if that is not enough, the 3rd circle will remove any doubt ^^.

Since regular phone emitters can burn laundry (after long exposition and having laundry nearby emitters) I think that a power of 1P is enough to damage on long terms a living being, but to damage in short time you would need something around 100P and 1000P. That's mean something like millions emitters (Depending how dense/sparse you place them) placed in a few square kilometers. The consumed electric power would be monstrous.

At that point you should drop your victim inside a field of tightly packed emitters, but wouldn't be better a regular bullet?

**the Vedict:**

**Possible doing that on ground**(but very hard and expensive) you would need ad hoc structures pre-built.

**Impossible with satellite network**, just from a pure cost point of view, putting [1Kg of material in orbit is $20000](https://www.quora.com/Rockets-What-is-cost-of-sending-1-kg-weight-into-space), assume a wave emitter is 10 Kg (not counting solar panels etc.) 1 million of wave emitters in orbit would be 10.000.000 kg which would cost 200.000.000.000 (not impossible having that money, but I'm assuming I can just make satellites appear from thin-space). But .. having 10 millions objects flying around is [asking for troubles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_debris). And don't pretend to be able to synchronize moving satellites ! :D

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.  Today I came across a blog post which (among other things) muses upon some theoretical capabilities of a large network of satellites.  Use ctrl+f starlink to jump to that section of this: https://caseyhandmer.wordpress.com/2021/11/17/science-upside-for-starship/ Does anything there change anything here?  It sounds to me as if the author anticipates using the satellite array to focus a lot of power on a single point in space.  Does your formula model omnidirectional emitters or directional ones?

Answer (score 0):

It's going to depend *a lot* on how powerful the transmitter is and even more on how narrowly and precisely the antennas can be aimed.

Generally speaking though, you're going to need roughly the same amount of power focused on the same amount of space as would be required to do it with a laser weapon operating at the same frequency.  Communications satellites are generally not designed to focus their beam down to a 1" circle at orbital distances, so you're going to need either something purpose-designed as a secret weapon, or a heck of a lot of them to get the required MW/sqin.

It would be far cheaper and more efficient to put a large fleet of mirrors into orbit and reflect sunlight onto the target than to try to put up enough comsats to cook anyone on the surface.  Disguise it as a "climate control system."